# How do you use a lookup table in Google Data Studio?

Tags: google-data-studio

So blended data in Google Data Studio is not a lookup table. Here is what I'm trying to do.

Say I have `data set A` that has sales data like this:

```
Name          | Product       | Price
Mary          | Baconator Gun | $45.00
Mary          | Germ Gun      | $29.00
Bill          | Germ Gun      | $29.00
```

And then I have this second data, `data set B`, that has the product category for all my sales:

```
Product       | Category
Baconator Gun | Hardware
Germ Gun      | Software
```

I can't use blended data to blend B into A in GDS because the same fields I want to report on must exist in both data sets in blended data. Blended data seems to be for mixing two common data sets, not a traditional lookup table.

The ultimate goal is I'm trying to create a report that shows my sales by category.

I can't seem to find any way to achieve a *lookup* in GDS. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I have built a demo of this, so unless you are missing data (for which you could create a field based on category, setting it as "uncategorised" or similar if empty) then I'm confident you can use Blended Data.

Source 1: Sales
Source 2: Categories

Blend data: Sales (left), Categories (right)
Join key: Product

Create table, source: Blended data
Dimension: Category
Metric: (SUM) Price

[image: Screenshot showing all settings and output]